# Simple timer start and stop from console

Tags: c#, .net, timer

Just a simple timer application for review.  Stop and start the timer from the command line.

The plan is to use this in a poker application to fold out a player if they don't act after a time period (call the clock on them).  I was trying to use async await but it did not seem like the right tool for this.

```
MyTimer myTimer = new MyTimer();
while (true)
{
    string readLine = Console.ReadLine();
    if (readLine == "stop")
    {
        myTimer.TimerStop();
    }
    else if (readLine == "start")
    {
        myTimer.TimerStart();
    }
    else if (readLine == "q")
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```

.

```
public class MyTimer
{
    private System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("The Elapsed event was raised at {0}", e.SignalTime);
        Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event was raised at {0}", e.SignalTime);
    }

    public void TimerStop()
    {
        aTimer.Enabled = false;
        Console.WriteLine("aTimer.Enabled = false");
    }
    public void TimerStart()
    {
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
        Console.WriteLine("aTimer.Enabled = true");
    }

    public MyTimer()
    {
        aTimer.Interval = 2000;
        // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
        aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        // Have the timer fire repeated events (true is the default)
        aTimer.AutoReset = true;
        // Start the timer
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
        Debug.WriteLine("aTimer.Enabled");
        Console.WriteLine("aTimer.Enabled");
    }
}
```

Comment: VTC can you tell me what else you are looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why aren't you inheriting from Timer it's not a sealed class and is disposable (and I believe must be disposed).

```
public class PokerTimer : Timer
{
    public PokerTimer() : this(2000)
    {

    }

    public PokerTimer(double interval) : base(interval)
    {
        AutoReset = true;
        Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        //clean up anything you need to here or remove this override.
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

All that being said, you said this is for a game where you want to time out players so you might want to look a bit into game loops and managing state in such a loop.

Comment: I will look into game loops.